# PGP With 2 x Yuibikey 4 + 1 USB (Backup)

Tags: pgp, yubikey

I have 2 Yubikey 4. 
I'd like to use them for PGP and overall for securing my online identity.
I'm [following this guide](https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide) but I'm stuck at backup step. The guide itself does not explain how to have keys on two yubico keys + backup.

My plan is:

1. Generate keys offline on an airgapped PC
2. Back them on a USB (store that USB in a safe deposit box)
3. Import on keys on first Yubikey 4
4. Import keys on the second Yubikey 4
5. Print out revoke certificate as QR and store it with USB in a deposit box.

I am Linux newbie, and I don't understand how I can export the encrypted keys onto a USB and then import them on Yubikeys. The backup key part of the tutorial][2](https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide#backup-keys) I'm following is quite hard to understand and I have no idea what I'm doing there.

1. Should I just copy the entire gpg folder on the key?
2. Is there an easy way to export encrypted keys to USB?

Can someone please help me with this step, I'm lost and I've been reading about how to safely create PGP on Yubikey for the past 9 days, but still haven't been able to do it.